# Where does cmake pull dependency paths from on OSX/Linux?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to build a project (opencv3), but it is referencing an old installation of a library. I have since removed the reference library, so my build fails. I have the required dependency installed elsewhere.

My question is, during cmakes configuration process, where does it pull references to system libraries from? Can I edit this source to remove references to the absent library?

Comment: What is difference between this question and [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637138/how-do-i-prevent-cmake-from-referencing-an-old-anaconda-installation)?

Comment: One could argue that they are slightly different (anaconda does not have a clean uninstallation routine). However I have deleted the dupe.

Comment: Did you try actions, suggested in comment for deleted question(remove `CMakeCache.txt` and rerun `cmake`)? It should work unless path to the library is hardcoded in the project.

Comment: Yes, but that had no effect. In the end I had to reinstall an installation of a library installed while I had anaconda present. It retained references to a library within anaconda.

Comment: I don't quite understand your situation: Do you have `opencv3` project **already installed**? And it refers to the library installation, which is removed(moved into another place)? If so, the only always-correct way is to reinstall `opencv3` project.